# Correctly implementing wait and notify in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

According to this document, using `wait` and `notify` is discouraged in Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

> wait()/notify()
>
> Effective Java Item 69 kindly suggests to prefer concurrency utilities to wait() and notify(). Thus, these methods are not available on references of type Any.

However the document does not propose any correct way of doing it.

Basically, I would like to implement a service, which would read the input data and process them. If there were no input data, it would suspend itself until someone notifies that there are new input data. Something like

```
while (true) {
    val data = fetchData()
    processData(data)
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        wait()
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I don't want to use these not recommended methods (antipatterns), I really want to find out how to do this properly.

In my case `fetchData` reads data from the database, so queues in my case cannot be used.

Comment: Did you check Effective Java Item 69?

Comment: You could use actors from Kotlin coroutines to implement your service. It waits for items to be sent to a channel. More info here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#actors

Comment: You can cast any object to `java.lang.Object` and implement such antipatterns easily.

Comment: Currently `actor` from coroutines is deprecated, so this is also not good option.

Answer (score 74):

In general you should use higher-level concurrency utilities when possible.

However, if none of the higher-level constructs work in your case, the direct
replacement is to use a
[`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and a single
[`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)
on that lock.

For example, if your Java code was something like:

```
private Object lock = new Object();

...

synchronized(lock) {
    ...
    lock.wait();
    ...
    lock.notify();
    ...
    lock.notifyAll();
    ...
}
```

You can change it to the following Kotlin:

```
private val lock = ReentrantLock()
private val condition = lock.newCondition()

lock.withLock {           // like synchronized(lock)
    ...
    condition.await()     // like wait()
    ...
    condition.signal()    // like notify()
    ...
    condition.signalAll() // like notifyAll()
    ...
}
```

While this is slightly more verbose, conditions do provide some extra
flexibility, as you can have multiple conditions on a single lock, and there
are also other kinds of locks (notably `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock` and
`ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock`).

Note that `withLock` is a Kotlin-provided extension function that takes care of calling `Lock.lock()`/`Lock.unlock()` before/after invoking the supplied lambda.

Comment: Kotlin also adds the `withLock` higher level function which makes this even nicer!

Comment: @JonTirsen Thanks! Somehow I'd missed the existence of `withLock` in the standard library (I swear I'd looked for something like this). I've updated the answer to use it.

Comment: you still have to use variable `boolean` to check if thread is waiting or not, so for me it's still better to use `synchronized` + `Object`

Comment: @user924 What do you mean?

Comment: Using `wait()`/`notify()` and `ReeantrantLock`/`Condition` together with Coroutines does not make sense. Both approaches block thread which is not acceptable in Couroutines.

Comment: Will that work in a mixed Java Kotlin environment?

Comment: @Martin it'll work, as long as the Java code is also using the same `ReentrantLock` and `Condition`. If you're gradually/partially porting a Java codebase to Kotlin, you many want to first port any locks in the Java code that the Kotlin code will need to directly interact with to use `ReentrantLock` instead of `synchonized`.

Comment: Not coroutine friendly.

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović is it any less coroutine friendly than blocking IO? The question had nothing to do with coroutines.

Comment: Well, this exactly **is** blocking IO, e.g. if you try to do this within a single coroutine it will deadlock. I agree the question is not specific, but since it's Kotlin it's worth pointing it out.

Answer (score 28):

A [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) can be a suitable high-level concurrency utility for your use case, but applying it requires knowing and modifying your code structure.

The idea is, `fetchData()` should [`.take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()) an item from the queue, and if the queue is empty, that will block the execution until an item appears, which eliminates the `.wait()` in your code. The producer of the data should [`.put(t)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#put(E)) the data into the queue.

---

If you *really* need to use `wait` and `notify`, e.g. for implementing a concurrency utility at low-level, you can cast a Kotlin object to `java.lang.Object` and call these functions afterwards, as said in [the language reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#waitnotify). Or, written as extension functions:

```
@Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")
private fun Any.wait() = (this as java.lang.Object).wait()
```

Comment: Ad BlockingQueue, in my case this wouldn't work, because when notified, I need to check the data in the database. Would there be something useful for it? Ad `notify`, I don't really need to use it, I just need to to find something suitable :-)

Comment: @Vojtěch Maybe a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)?

Comment: Instead of the cast and @Suppress, create dedicated `val lock=Object()`, and use any `synchronized(lock){ lock.wait(); lock.notify()}` on that. This is without compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post the unit tests to GitHub when I can. Java style wait, wait(timeout), notify using coroutines.

```
package com.spillikinaerospace.android.core

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel

/**
 * A Kotlin coroutines friendly method of implementing Java wait/notify.
 *
 * Exist safely on mis-matched calls. More than one wait is ignored as
 * is more than one notify if no wait was called. Only works with 2 threads. No notifyall.  
 *
 * See Locks
 * https://proandroiddev.com/synchronization-and-thread-safety-techniques-in-java-and-kotlin-f63506370e6d
 */
class SAWaitNotify {

    private val channel: Channel<Unit> = Channel<Unit>(0)
    // re-enrty block.
    private var waitingForNotify = false

    /**
     * Wait until Notify is called.
     */
    public fun saWait() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (waitingForNotify) {
                return
            }
            waitingForNotify = true
        }

        // block forever until notify
        runBlocking {
            channel.receive()
        }

        synchronized(this) {
            waitingForNotify = false
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wait until Notify is called or the given number of seconds have passed.
     *
     * @param seconds - Max delay before unlock.
     */
    public fun saWait(seconds: Long) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (waitingForNotify) {
                return
            }
            waitingForNotify = true
        }

        // block until timeout or notify
        runBlocking {
            // Setup our delty before calling offer.
            val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO)
            {
                delay((seconds * 1000))
                channel.offer(Unit)
            }
            // This will continue when someone calls offer.
            channel.receive()
            // Somebody called offer. Maybe the timer, maybe saNotify().
            // Channel has released but the timer job may still be running.
            // It's ok to call this even if the job has finished.
            job.cancel()
        }

        synchronized(this) {
            waitingForNotify = false
        }
    }

    /**
     * Release wait()
     */
    public fun saNotify() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (waitingForNotify == false) {
                return
            }
            waitingForNotify = false
        }
        channel.offer(Unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: wait() should not tolerate a call from a second thread. This would be a coding mistake that one should know about.  Modified the re-entry locks to read...



            if (waitingForNotify) {

                throw IllegalStateException("Wait() called by a second thread before notify().")

            }

Answer (score 0):

```
inline fun <T : Object, R> sync(lock: T, block: T.() -> R): R {
    synchronized(lock) {
        return lock.block()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val lock = Object()

sync(lock) {
    wait()
    notify()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [kotlin Semaphore](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/index.html) to suspend the coroutine instead of blocking a thread:

```
val semaphore = Semaphore(1, 0)

suspend fun runFetchLoop() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
    while (isActive) {
        val data = fetchData()
        processData(data)
        semaphore.acquire()
        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            semaphore.acquire()
        }
        semaphore.release()
    }
}

fun notifyDataAvailable() = semaphore.release()
```

Here is a running example: https://pl.kotl.in/bnKeOspfs .

However I would prefer a *cold* [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) or a *hot* [Channel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/produce.html) to solve this problem. Here is a good [article](https://medium.com/@elizarov/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9) about cold flows and hot channels of the great Roman Elizarov

Comment: I think the example in this answer is wrong. There is a race condition. I assume, that `notify()` is called after `fetchData()` returns something different than before. If `notify()` is called after `data.isEmpty()` is true, but before `mutex.lock()`, then coroutine waiting on `mutex.lock()` will wait forever.

Comment: @PavelČernocký you are right. To fix it, I replaced the mutex by a semaphore and two acquire calls. This chains condition and suspension together. If the notify call comes in between the isEmpty condition and the acquire call, then it won't result in an unwanted unlimited suspension anymore.

Comment: This fix has another problems. `acquire()`/`release()` has to be in pair what is not guaranteed here. Especially when `notifyDataAvailable()` is called multiple times, it will throw an exception, because there will be no `Semaphore` permits to release. In general i don't see this approach is right, it certainly can not be generalized. The whole `while` is constructed badly. `data` is local variable which is filled by `fetchData`, so `fetchData` should be coordinated with `notifyDataAvailable`.