# Kotlin IllegalMonitorStateException in @Synchronized method

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency

I am trying to reproduce a old-school solution in Kotlin to classic Consumer-Producer problem with multiple threads and shared memory space. In **Java** I would use synchronized methods to access a shared space. In **Kotlin**, however, it seems that `@Synchronized` annotated method is throwing `IllegalMonitorStateException`. I was expecting that annotated methods should behave exactly as they do in **Java** but it seems that is not the case. I solved the problem with `synchronized(){}` function but I'm still puzzled that `@Synchronized` doesn't work. **Why is that?**

In the following code, Producer "produces" a new value by incrementing a counter (Long) inside `SynchronizedBox` and Consumer reads that value then prints it to console.

Kotlin MessageBox that does **not** work

```
package concurrency.producer_consumer

class MessageBox(var message: Long = 0): SynchronizedBox {
    private val lock = Object()
    private var empty = true

    @Synchronized
    override fun syncIncrement() {
        while (!empty) {
            lock.wait()
        }

        message++
        empty = false
        lock.notifyAll()
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun readValue(): Long {
          while (empty) {
              lock.wait()
          }

          val readValue = message
          empty = true
          lock.notifyAll()

          return readValue
    }
}
```

Java variant that works:

```
package concurrency.producer_consumer;

public class JBox implements SynchronizedBox {
    private long value = 0;
    private boolean empty = true;

    @Override
    public synchronized void syncIncrement() {
        while (!empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        value++;
        empty = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized long readValue() {
        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        empty = true;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Kotlin version that actually works:

```
package concurrency.producer_consumer

class MessageBox(var message: Long = 0): SynchronizedBox {
    private val lock = Object()
    private var empty = true

    override fun syncIncrement() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (!empty) {
                lock.wait()
            }

            message++
            empty = false
            lock.notifyAll()
        }
    }

    override fun readValue(): Long {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (empty) {
                lock.wait()
            }

            empty = true
            lock.notifyAll()
            return message
        }
    }
}
```

Rest of the code:

**Consumer**:
    package concurrency.producer_consumer

```
class Consumer(private val messageBox: SynchronizedBox): Runnable {

    override fun run() {
        println("consumer thread: ${Thread.currentThread().id}: started")

        while (true) {
            println("consumer: ${messageBox.readValue()}")
            Thread.sleep(1_000)
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer**:

```
class Producer(private val messageBox: SynchronizedBox): Runnable {

    override fun run() {
        println("producer thread: ${Thread.currentThread().id}: started")

        while (true) {
            messageBox.syncIncrement()
            Thread.sleep(1_000)
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
package concurrency.producer_consumer

interface SynchronizedBox {
    fun syncIncrement()
    fun readValue(): Long
}
```

**Launcher**

```
package concurrency.producer_consumer

fun main() {
    val box: SynchronizedBox = MessageBox()
    val producer1 = Producer(box)
    val consumer = Consumer(box)

    val threadP1 = Thread(producer1)
    val threadC = Thread(consumer)

    threadP1.start()
    threadC.start()
}
```

Comment: Is this getting confused about the lock objects?  In the non-working Kotlin version, `@Synchronized` locks on the `MessageBox` instance, but it's `wait()`ing on and `notify()`ing the `lock` object instead.  This is unlike the Java version, which does everything on the `MessageBox` instances, and unlike the working Kotlin version, which does everything on the `lock` object.  (`@Synchronized` should work exactly as in Java: see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/)

Comment: @gidds so how do I `wait` and `notify` on `MessageBox` instead, in non-working case? I know that MessageBox does not inherit Object's `wait` and `notify` methods and even if I inherit directly from Object it does not work (I've tried).

Comment: Kotlin's designers were probably trying to discourage using the low-level monitors at all, as they're fiddly and error-prone.  There are a couple of ideas in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44589962/10134209.  But I'd recommend seeing whether you can use a higher-level abstraction, such as a BlockingQueue, or the Executor framework, or kotlin.concurrent classes, or actors — many people have been down this road before!

Comment: I'm aware of the alternative but it's not what I am after. I'm trying to understand what is happening behind the scenes so I actually need to figure out how locking and synchronization works in **Kotlin**.

Comment: @gidds, you were right and I figured out that I've made few mistakes when extending `Object`. I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that indeed `@Synchronized` locks on `MessageBox` and it doesn't work only because in Kotlin everything extends `Any` instead of Java's `Object`. Although it is not recommended way of doing concurrent programming in **Kotlin**, the solution is to simply extend Object as shown below in `MessageBoxLock`:

```
package concurrency.producer_consumer.message_box

@Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")
class MessageBoxLock(var message: Long = 0): Object(), SynchronizedBox {

    private var empty = true

    @Synchronized
    override fun syncIncrement() {
        while (!empty) {
            wait()
        }

        message++
        empty = false
        notifyAll()
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun readValue(): Long {

        while (empty) {
            wait()
        }

        empty = true
        notifyAll()

        return message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, so instead of annotating with **@Synchronized** keyword, I have changed to **synchronized call** as shown below, and it worked for me.

```
private fun produce() = synchronized(lock){
   ...
}
```

**Kotlin** code example to look through:

```
fun main() {
    val producer = Producer()
    producer.name = "PRODUCER-THREAD"
    producer.start()
    val consumer = Consumer(producer)
    consumer.name = "CONSUMER-THREAD"
    consumer.start()
}

class Consumer(private val producer: Producer) : Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                val data = producer.consume()
                println("$data consumed by: ${currentThread().name}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

class Producer : Thread() {
    override fun run() {
        try {
            while (true) produce()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun produce() = synchronized(lock) {
        while (messages.size == MAX_SIZE) lock.wait()

        val data = LocalDateTime.now().toString()
        messages.add(data)
        println("Data produced")
        lock.notify()
    }

    fun consume(): String = synchronized(lock) {
        lock.notify()
        while (messages.isEmpty()) lock.wait()

        val data = messages[0]
        println("Data consumed as: $data")
        messages.remove(data)
        return data
    }

    companion object {
        const val MAX_SIZE = 3
        val lock = Object()
        val messages = arrayListOf<String>()
    }
}
```